# Old apple push notification is received by user

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

we are using Amazon Simple Push Notifications to push the notifications to APNS. We had our app certificate changed around December 2015 and missed out to update in AWS. Thus, the notifications is failed to deliver to user.

We update the certificate in AWS in June 2016 and we had user complaints that he received a lot of notifications. After we troubleshoot, we found that the notifications that user received is the notifications we sent between December 2015 to May 2016 but this should not happening as the notifications should be failed to deliver to user.

We had check with AWS and they mentioned that their services is to deliver the message to APNS and nothing much can do from their end.

Thus, we would like to request for help to troubleshoot for this issue.

There are few questions we would like to ask:
1. How long is the notifications will be cache if it do not able to deliver to user?
2. Is the notifications services have any retry mechanism?
3. Anyway we can reset/kill all notifications that we have sent to APNS?
4. Any possible scenario that the notifications will be keep for half year long?

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
We tried to use the following steps to reproduce the issue but we not able to reproduce the issue.

1. Revoke the push notifications certificate in app configuration.
2. Send few notifications.
3. Update the new push notifications certificate.
4. Test if the notifications sent after push notification is revoked will be received by user.

Comment: What about the [TTL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-ttl.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, we will try to specify the TTL for the message. However, we are still curious if there any way to cancel all old message that has been sent?

Comment: Doubtful, but this is not really my area of expertise.